# Show that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am supposed to use the definition of uniform continuity to show that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ is uniformly continuous.
I'd appreciate it if you could look over my proof and tell me whether it is correct and what I could do to improve it.
$$|x-x_0|\lt\delta\implies \left|\frac{1}{1+|x|}-\frac{1}{1+|x_0|}\right|\lt\epsilon$$

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+|x|}-\frac{1}{1+|x_0|}\right| = \left|\frac{1+|x|-(1+|x_0|)}{(1+|x|)(1+|x_0|)}\right| =\left|\frac{|x|-|x_0|}{1+|x|+|x_0|+|x||x_0|}\right|$$

$$\le \left|\frac{|x-x_0|}{1+|x|+|x_0|+|x||x_0|}\right|=
|x-x_0|\left|\frac{1}{1+|x|+|x_0|+|x||x_0|}\right| \le|x-x_0|\lt\delta $$
Let $\delta = \epsilon \implies$ f is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: Move the $\delta=\epsilon$ statement to the top of your proof and then it is perfect

Comment: $=|x-x_0|\frac{1}{1+|x|+|x_0|+|x||x_0|}|$  is missing a vertical bar

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you're right. I edited it

Comment: @StanTendijck Could you explain what difference that makes? Thank you.

Comment: The difference is that it makes it a bit more formal. The statement you need to prove is that for all epsilon, you can find a delta such that something holds. Essentially, the idea is that you first search for a suitable $\delta$ as you did. But then once you complete the proof, you move the definition of $\delta$ after the choose any $\epsilon$. It is just a convention to stick to the order of the statement you try to prove if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct (although adding *slightly* more prose would make it nicer).

Alternatively, if you know derivatives, you can argue in the following way:

1. $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, so it is uniformly continuous there.
2. The $f'$ exists and $\lvert f'\rvert$ is bounded by $1$ in $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$, so $f$ is uniformly continuous in each of these intervals.
3. If a function $f$ is uniformly continuous on two intersecting intervals $I_1,I_2$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I_1\cup I_2$.
4. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous in each of $(-\infty,0)$, $[-1,1]$ and $(0,\infty)$, it is uniformly continuous on their union (by the preceding point).

Edit: as suggested in the comments, you can avoid considering $[-1,1]$ separately, and instead use the fact that $f'$ exists and is bounded in $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ to conclude that $f$ is uniformly continuous in each of $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$, and then conclude as in the last point.

Comment: The mean value theorem uses only the derivative in the *interior* of an interval. Therefore in (2) you can conclude that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $(-\infty, 0]$ and $[0, \infty)$, that makes (1) unnecessary.

Comment: @MartinR: that is true. Still, this way you can avoid deliberating about where the derivative exists etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than finishing the series of equalities and inequalities with $<\delta$, you should say:

> given $\varepsilon>0$, we can take $\delta=\varepsilon$ and for $|x-x_0|<\delta$ we have
>   $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le|x-x_0|<\delta=\varepsilon$$